# Python and Cisco Routers over USB -> Serial -> Console cable

Tags: python, console, cisco

Okay, so I'm wondering if someone can point me in the right direction for this. I'm trying to use Python to automatically send commands to a Cisco router. Namely so that I can make an automatic configuration program that integrates with a spreadsheet of ours (That I'm hoping to move over to a database).

So, I looked into it and found a few Serial classes that would allow me to send commands to the router, however I'm a little bit confused because my knowledge doesn't extend to the point where I can tell if any of them have what I need. What I need is

1) Being able to detect when the router is ready to receive commands and not (So I can set it to wait till a router is done rebooting)

2) Being able to read configs (or atleast the output after I enter a command) (So that I can do automatic quality assurance on the configs

Also, the last thing that confuses me is my cable (as in the topic). It's a USB to Serial cable, and then a Serial to Console cable. The library that I was looking at either selected the nth serial port or a direct address, and I'm not sure that would work with my cable

Answer (score 1):

Typically your OS either has drivers, or you can install drivers, that make a USB-serial adapter appear as an ordinary serial port (with a number or a name, depending on your OS conventions).

A module such as [`pySerial`](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/) has functions for both *writing* and *reading* data from the serial port. When you send the router commands, it will respond with some data you can read (this is the same thing that you see when you talk to the router manually). In pseudocode, you might:

```
read data from the router until it shows a "ready" prompt of some kind
while you have commands to send:
    send a command
    read the response, and keep reading until the next "ready" prompt
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly check the below link to know how to install drive for your Console-USB cable :

[connecting-to-the-serial-console](https://www.cyberciti.biz/hardware/5-linux-unix-commands-for-connecting-to-the-serial-console/)

then 
try Minicom app Or Putty app for linux and Windows to retrieve your Configuration